# Picture not showing in main blog page Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have recently created blog, all is fine ecxept pictures no showing in main blog page

Pictures are visible when I open particular post
[pictures are shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOLwK.jpg)

When I enter main blog page pictures are gone
[no pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYr1q.png)

Pictures are added in admin using WYSIWYG editor froala_editor.

I use below to display blog view
blog.py

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for post in object_list %}
    <h5>{{ post.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}<a href="{{post.id}}"> <b> {{ post.title    }}</b></a></h5>
    <!--<img src="{{ post.img.url }}" class="img-responsive" >-->
    {{ post.body|safe|linebreaks|truncatechars:400 }}


{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I would be grateful for responses

Comment: can you give me your `models.py` and `views.py`?

Comment: Hi :) why the fifth line is commented?

Comment: i just hope the actual problem isn't it..

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
<!--<img src="{{ post.img.url }}" class="img-responsive" >-->
```

With

```
<img src="{{ post.img.url }}" class="img-responsive" >
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sanca Kembang

models.py

```
'django.db import models
from django_markdown.models import MarkdownField

#dodany model aby mozna bylo dodac kategorie#
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nazwa Kategorii', max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField('Odnosnik', unique=True, max_length=100)
    #icon = models.ImageField('Ikonka Kategorii', upload_to='icons',      blank=True#)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Kategoria"
        verbose_name_plural = "Kategoria"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
 #-----------------------------------------------------#
 #Froala
from django.db import models
from froala_editor.fields import FroalaField



class Post(models.Model):
    body = FroalaField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    #body = MarkdownField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name='Kategoria')
    #img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', default='DEFAULT VALUE')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title' views.py 'from django.shortcuts import render
```

## Create your views here.

' this what I have

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
```

@ Riccardo Leschiutta

add beginning this line was without comment because I thought it's gonna help - but didn't and I left it commented out

```
<!--<img src="{{ post.img.url }}" class="img-responsive" >-->
```